# Есть ли синоним к "жене учителя"?

Tags: синонимы

"Учительша" — звучит некрасиво. [https://kartaslov.ru/синонимы-к-слову/учительша](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83/%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

Слово **учительша** включено в словари, правда, как разговорное. В определённом контексте можно использовать другое разговорное слово: **благоверная**. Лучшим же синонимом будет выражение **супруга учителя**, но оно носит несколько официальный характер и не исключает случая, когда супруга также является учителем. Ещё одно синонимичное выражение **хозяйка в доме (семье) учителя**, которое, если и может быть понято неоднозначное, то во всяком случае не хуже (в этом отношении), чем **учительша**.

Comment: "Благоверная" и "супруга" (учителя) - это синонимы к слову жена: не совсем то, что надо. А если, к примеру, я возьму (в тексте) слово "учительша" в кавычки...

Comment: Это слово много раз будет встречаться в тексте?

Comment: Всего один раз.

Comment: Тогда я не знаю, что посоветовать. В кавычки брать плохо. Это должно было бы означать необычное употребление слова. А здесь как раз обычное, хотя и в разговорном стиле.

Comment: Лучше сказать "его жена" или "его супруга", чем искать невесть что. Почему нельзя - то?

Comment: Напишите тичавайф, взяв в ковычки, и будете автором нового англицизма!

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли синоним к “жене учителя”?

Полагаю, что нет. Разумеется речь идет о синонимах синтетических (в одно слово), образованных с помощью суффиксов типа *-их(а), -иц(а), -ш(а), -к(а)* и подобных.

Русский язык при всем богатстве моделей суффиксального словообразования по историческим причинам вообще не позаботился о возможности как-то разнести по значению феминитивы, обозначающие жену представителя профессии и собственно женщину, представляющую такую профессию.
Чаще всего есть только одно слово, соединяющее оба значения: докторша, купчиха, врачиха, атаманша.

При этом одно из значений как правило либо устаревшее, либо сугубо разговорное. "Купчиха", пожалуй единственное исключение в этом ряду, то есть имеющее два нормативных (пусть и устаревающих) равноправных значения - да и то тут скорее не о жене купца речь идет, а о дочери.

Иногда одно из значений полностью вытесняет другое (*ткачиха с поварихой* -тут, полагаю, Пушкин постарался - *пловчиха, вахтерша, стюардесса, продавщица*  против *генеральша, полковница, солдатка* - и прочие жены военных, редкие *председательша, секретарша, дворничиха -  исторически "жена секретаря, дворника", мельничиха, кузнечиха, возможно, *шофёрша*)

Но всегда это одно слово. Исключение, очень условное, вспоминается только одно. Лесничиха - жена лесника, лесничая - жена лесника. Оба слова разговорные, на грани нормативности, но и тут объяснение в том, что эти формы имеют разные порождающие слова: лесник и лесничий.

Другие попытки разделить эти два значения (стихийной волей носителей) успехом не увенчались. Скажем, одно время всерьез предлагалось считать профессоршу - женщиной-профессором, а профессориху - его, профессора, женой. Народ очень быстро запутался, кто из них кто, видимо, это одна из причин, почему в целом такое разделение не приживается.

Из всего этого делаю однозначный вывод: ваши поиски вряд ли увенчаются успехом. Тем более, что слова, обозначающие женщин по профессии мужа, в целом устаревают.

(+)===

> А если, к примеру, я возьму (в тексте) слово "учительша" в кавычки

Если вам очень хочется написать что-то такое в кавычках, напишите "учител**иха**". Это даже без кавычек понятно, хотя и явно ненормативно. Просто этот суффикс, пожалуй, наиболее продуктивен в роли обозначения жены.